# Initializing subclass on object creation in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to intialize a subclass in fabric.js after an object is created on canvas.  I have defined the following subclass:

```
var Route = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Path, {

        type: 'routePath',

        initialize: function(options) {
                options || (options = {});
                this.callSuper('initialize', options);
        },
});
```

Then, I listen for object creations, and would like to convert the created `fabric.Path` to an instance of my `Route` subclass:

```
canvas.on('object:added', function(options) {
    var createdObject = options.target;
    var route = new Route(createdObject.toObject());
});
```

The code above does not seem to work. If I inspect the `route` variable after it's created, it does not have any of the properties that the `createdObject` had. It seems that all of the settings are showing as default values.

**EDIT**

To simply even further, I'm just trying to create a new instance of one of my `Route` classes. I am passing in a `width` option, to test if the newly created object contains that width:

```
var testRoute = new Route({width: 150});
alert(testRoute.getWidth()); //alerts 0
```

Why is the width 0 and not 150? Is there something wrong with the way I am creating the `Route` subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was using the wrong constructor definition.  Here's working code:

```
var Route = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Path, {

        type: 'routePath',

        initialize: function(path, options) {
                options || (options = {});
                this.callSuper('initialize', path, options);
        },
});

canvas.on('object:added', function(options) {
    var route = new SlopeRoute(options.target.path, options.target.toObject());
});
```